# Java/Jsp XML Dom

Tags: java, xml, jsp, dom

looks like I need help again! :-/

Im trying to read this XML file with Java/Jsp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"  ?>
<universal_campaign>
    <campaign_details>
        <campaign_id></campaign_id>
        <campaign_title>Test Campaign</campaign_title>
        <campaign_sdate>2010-01-21</campaign_sdate>
        <campaign_edate>2010-01-25</campaign_edate>
        <campaign_priority>Normal</campaign_priority>
    </campaign_details>

    <campaign_schedule>
        <schedule_sdate>2010-01-25</schedule_sdate>
        <schedule_edate>2010-01-30</schedule_edate>
        <schedule_priority>Normal</schedule_priority>

        <schedule_content>
            <content_name>Wallpaper_A</content_name>
            <content_filename>WP_A.jpg</content_filename>
        </schedule_content>

        <schedule_content>
            <content_name>Screensaver</content_name>
            <content_filename>SCS.gif</content_filename>
        </schedule_content>


        <schedule_zone>universal.001 test 001</schedule_zone>
        <schedule_zone>universal.001 test 002</schedule_zone>
        <schedule_zone>universal.001 test 003</schedule_zone>
    </campaign_schedule>

</universal_campaign>
```

Here is my Java/Jsp code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(fileName);
NodeList nl, nl2;
NodeList campaign_details = doc.getElementsByTagName("universal_campaign");
String res = "";

for(int i = 0;i<campaign_details.getLength();i++){

  nl = campaign_details.item(i).getChildNodes();

  for(int j = 0; j<nl.getLength();j++){                            
    nl2 = nl.item(j).getChildNodes();

      for(int k = 0; k<nl2.getLength();k++){
        res += nl2.item(k).getNodeName()+": "+nl2.item(k).getNodeValue()+"<br />";
      }
   }

}
```

But when I output the String res, I get:

```
#text: 
campaign_id: null
#text: 
campaign_title: null
#text: 
campaign_sdate: null
#text: 
campaign_edate: null
#text: 
campaign_priority: null
#text: 
#text: 
schedule_sdate: null
#text: 
schedule_edate: null
#text: 
schedule_priority: null
#text: 
schedule_content: null
#text: 
schedule_content: null
#text: 
schedule_zone: null
#text: 
schedule_zone: null
#text: 
schedule_zone: null
#text:
```

And I don't get it... how can the getNodeName() return the name of the node, but the getNodeValue() returns null....?
Please help me, I have done many search and failed attempts before posting here, but nothing worked.... :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact is that the node you're getting is not the text node itself. It's an [`Element`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html) and `getNodeValue` will return null (see table [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html)). You'll have to use [`getTextContent`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent()) instead.

Comment: Thanks it worked! but I still have the "#text:" appearing in my output... why?

Comment: Because of the line returns in your XML. The space is treated as a text node with nothing in it except blank characters. So if you know which elements you want, you'd better only filter on these elements.

Answer (score 2):

Use `getTextContent()` or, even better, use a better XML API ([jdom](http://www.jdom.org/) springs to mind).

Comment: Thanks it worked! but I still have the "#text:" appearing in my output... why?

I will check jdom out! Thanks for the advice.